# How to get all locations connected to a SmartThings account using Python?

Tags: python, api, smartthings

How to get the name of all location you have connected to your SmartThings account using Python with the pysmartthings libary?

I tryed this code from the documentation to the libary :

```
import aiohttp
import pysmartthings

token = 'PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN'

async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    api = pysmartthings.SmartThings(session, token)
    locations = await api.locations()
    print(len(locations))

    location = locations[0]
    print(location.name)
    print(location.location_id)
```

but i got this error : *SyntaxError: 'async with' outside async function*
then i tryed a code from youtube :

```
import aiohttp
import pysmartthings

token = 'PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN'

async def get_locations():
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            api = pysmartthings.SmartThings(session, token)
            locations = await api.locations()
            for location in locations:
                print(location.name)
                print(location.location_id)
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e)
```

but got no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things missing..  With code snippet 2: The one is that you have defined a function and don't call it.. Try adding some simple  'print statements' to help find out what is happening. You can read up on the 'asyncio' at https://superfastpython.com/asyncio-coroutine-was-never-awaited/

Remember functionality is limited by the operations permitted by the token

Comment: My Token have full permissions

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).